# Display Web cam Python

Tags: python, opencv, qt-designer

I have this code for web cam and should be displayed in the window (designed in Qt designer) this code works well but now i have two cam windows, one in my Main window (form designed in Qt Designer) and one out of the Main window.

```
def b1_clicked(self):
    mycam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    if mycam.isOpened(): 

        _, frame = mycam.read()

    else:
        _, frame = False

    while (True):
        cv2.imshow("preview", frame)
        _, frame = mycam.read()
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.cv.CV_BGR2RGB)
        image = QtGui.QImage(frame, frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0],frame.strides[0], QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888)
        self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(image))
        key = cv2.waitKey(20)
        if key == 27: # escape ESC
            break
```

Please any suggestion how to kill and make it not visible the form which is out of the Main window.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Comment out cv2.imshow which opens its own window.